# Database sqlite android rewrite

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

In my android app, i create a sqlite database in onCreate() method and it is filled with informations that i get from a csv file on my server.

My problem is that everytime the app is launched, my db is filled with same information once again (so if the app is launched 3 times i will have my db filled 3 times with same data).

First launch:

```
ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
```

Second:

```
ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
```

Third:

```
ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
3           Paul        32          California  20000.0
4           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
5           Paul        32          California  20000.0
6           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
```

How can i handle this situation? I would like that my db would be filled only if data in csv are not in the db.

Any idea?

Comment: Yes. Use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`. Already existing items will be **updated** (`even if they have the same values`) and non existing items will be **inserted**.

Comment: will everytime replacing the existing columns create unwanted cpu overhead?

Comment: Nope, just tried db.replace(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) instead of db.insert and i get same problem

Comment: Deleting all columns onStop() application can be a good idea?

Comment: Do you get duplicate IDs, or not? (The examples are inconsistent.)

Comment: just give a shot to the answer which i have posted, i use the same mechanism for my application :P

Comment: @CL. IDs are not duplicate

Comment: Then what happens when there are two people with the same name? Is there some unique identifier in the CSV data?

Comment: @CL. in the CSV there aren't two people with same name. In sqlite db one contact will be inserted 2 times if app will be launched 2 times, with different and incremental ID (primary key)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("select ID from TABLE where ID = 1;", null);

if(cursor.getCount()==0)
{
  // now you can insert the record
}
else
{
  // your handle
}
```